# Firebase Fabric Crashlytics not sending data to server

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I used Crashlytics for a long time since it was under the Twitter umbrella. I'm switching now to the new version integrated with Firebase but I can't get it to work correctly. I think I've done the integration correctly. Everything looks ok. However data doesn't get sent (or received). I think the problem is in this message that I get in the debug console (Xcode).

```
[Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=FABNetworkError Code=-5 "(null)" UserInfo={status_code=403, type=2, request_id=617cbe85f1d8e3c3973b275a8ff08564, content_type=application/json; charset=utf-8}
```

I believe that for some reason, the SDK is failing to download the configuration settings needed to then connect to the server and send back the crash reports. Firebase looks like is working fine, so it's an issue specific with Fabric/Crashlytics.

I couldn't find any answer to this specific error. Anyone else experiencing this?

To add to this, I can't see the new version of the app appearing in the dashboard. And this update has been released already to the public... with hundreds of thousands of installs already.

Comment: It seems like this may be a good case to contact Firebase support about. You can contact for technical support or file a bug report [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/).

Comment: have you resolved this issue?

Comment: I'm facing the same "issue", seeing the error when running app on simulator but not when running on device. When running on device you should see something like `[Crashlytics] Version 3.10.2 (130)` if your app is set up correctly.

Comment: I have the same issue, just contacted Firebase for technical support

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the SDK doesn't recognise automatically the API Key that you should be able to set in the Info.plist.

Instead I had to pass it over to the URL in the build settings. (Old way to do it)...

Answer (score -1):

If your app is running with "App Sandbox" capability, enable the "Outgoing Connections" checkbox.

[image: App Sandbox -> Outgoing Connections]